# Tkinter - How to insert text at the beginning of the text box?

Tags: python, textbox, tkinter

I am using Python 2.7.5 and Tkinter. I am writing status messages into a text widget. To insert I am using:

```
text_widget.insert(INSERT, 'my status here.\n')
```

This works fine. However, each status is added after the previous status. How do I insert new lines at the top of the `Text` widget so that the most recent status is at the top, while keeping the previous status messages below?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

```
text_widget.insert('1.0', 'my status here.\n')
```

In short, the text widget can be indexed using a string notation of the form `"lineNum.columnNum"`, as well as using the special indices like `Tkinter.INSERT`.

I would recommend reading [effbot's documentation for the Tkinter text widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), or [New Mexico Tech's Tkinter Handbook](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html), which I've found has fewer examples and explanations, but  is more complete as an API reference.

Comment: Wow, thanks!!, long day here. I looked and looked at that, but I was doing the indexing wrong and in the wrong place of my arguments. So I finally broke down and asked here. Thanks again!

Comment: @Brionius what is 1.0 in that

Comment: @GHOSTH4CK3R It's a special Tkinter coordinate notation for text widgets - it has the form "lineNum.columnNum". So the 1 means line #1, and the 0 means column 0 (the first character in the line). So, "1.0" puts the inserted text right at the beginning of the text widget.