# Tkinter Print Given Text Into A Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a program that shows you what did you do and gives an opportunity to save your deeds and remind them. I did the getting info part and write it to a txt file but taking the info from it and printing in the Text section is what couldn't I do.

This is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title('Hatırlatıcı')

def write():
    text = et.get()
    file_one = open('jobs.txt', 'a')
    file_one.write('{}'.format(text))
    file_one.write('\n')
    file_one.close()

def read():
    file_open = open('jobs.txt', 'r')
    if file_open.mode == 'r':
        contents = file_open.read()
    tarea.insert(contents)
    file_open.close()

def al():
    write()
    read()

lb1 = Label(window, text='What Did You Do?', fg='red', font=("Times", 14,         
"bold"), cursor='tcross', justify='center') 
et = Entry(font=("Comic Sans MS", 10, "bold"))
b1 = Button(text='Confirm', command=al)
tarea = Text(width='50')
lb1.pack()
et.pack()
b1.pack()
tarea.pack()
et.place(x='30',y='65')
b1.place(x='220',y='65')
tarea.place(x='45',y='150')
window.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-22-4e2d8f6740e1>", line 22, in al
    read()
  File "<ipython-input-22-4e2d8f6740e1>", line 17, in read
    tarea.insert(contents)
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-22-4e2d8f6740e1>", line 22, in al
    read()
  File "<ipython-input-22-4e2d8f6740e1>", line 17, in read
    tarea.insert(contents)
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [insert documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm) clearly covers, the method requires two arguments: the index (a Text-form index) and text to insert.  For instance

```
tarea.insert(INSERT, contents)
```

will insert at the front.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346206/python-tkinter-how-to-insert-text-at-the-beginning-of-the-text-box#18346296) for more details.

Comment: It gave me that error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-31-481f7ca120db>", line 22, in al
    read()
  File "<ipython-input-31-481f7ca120db>", line 17, in read
    tarea.insert(0, contents)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3272, in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0"

Comment: My error; the index has to be of proper Text.index type.

Comment: and how can i add a clear function? I tried this:def clear():
    tarea.delete(INSERT)